# Can every polynomial be moved to a irreducible one?

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

Given a polynomial $P(x)$ in $Q[x]$, can I always find a rational number, $c$, so that $P(x)+c$ is irreducible in $Q[x]$?

Comment: By clearing denominators, which does not affect whether a polynomial can be factored, we may as well assume $P(x) \in \Bbb Z[x]$, in which case a factorization over $\Bbb Q$ is necessarily a factorization over $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: The answer is almost surely yes, but I have no idea for a proof yet.

Answer (score 3):

I just recalled a neat lemma which solves this:
Like Travis said we first move to $Z[x]$ and use the following lemma:

If a polynomial $P=a_nx^n+..+a_0 $ over $Z$ satisfies $a_0$ is prime and 
$|a_0|>|a_n|+|a_{n-1}|..+|a_1| $ then it is irreducible. A proof can be found here:
http://yufeizhao.com/olympiad/intpoly.pdf page 2